# Running a script continuously while schedule the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have two scripts that I would like to run simultaneously. While one will be scheduled to run every minute, I would like the second to continuously run.

I also would like both to run according to a schedule.
This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import time 

import schedule
import time

def job(): 
starttime=time.time() #runs every minute with 1 minute sleep
while True:
     %run "script_1.py"
     time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))

schedule.every().monday.at("14:00").do(job)
while True:
schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
```

I need to squeeze script_2 in this script and make it run continuously within this schedule.

Note: I am using jupyter notebook

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package has flexible job scheduling (e.g. run every minute, run every monday at 14:00, etc) and it can run multiple jobs.

Comment: I tried it and it was giving me module error even after installing it.. I also tried with an older version (2.2) and still did not work I am using python 3.6

Comment: I suggest to try and run the step-by-step examples on: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html

Comment: I will try again. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry man, tried everything and still getting this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'scheduler' from 'apscheduler.schedulers' (/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/__init__.py)`

Comment: is it possible to run one script every 30 minutes and then run another right after the first is finished? And do this on an interval with apscheduler? I've been trying with no luck. the scripts usually overlap with eachother